# Keras ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe keeps on loading

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, dataset

I'm working on the [MURA dataset](https://stanfordmlgroup.github.io/competitions/mura/) by Stanford. I'm trying to load the dataset using Keras's ImageDataGenerator. The data is in the following hierarchy:

[image: The directory hierarchy]

The `study1_positive` folder contains the images.

`ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory` cannot be used with this folder structure, therefore I tried using the `flow_from_dataframe` method.

However, when run, the code keeps on executing and doesn't stop.

Following is the format of the Pandas DataFrame that I'm passing to the `flow_from_directory` method:

[image: The DataFrame passed to flow_from_dataframe]

I've also tried changing the labels to 'abnormal' and 'normal' in place of 1 and 0, respectively.

EDIT:

I've pasted the code below:

```
train_imggen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, rotation_range=30,
                              horizontal_flip=True)

train_loader = train_imggen.flow_from_dataframe(traindf, '.', shuffle=True,
                                            x_col='path', y_col='label',
                                            color_mode='grayscale',
                                            target_size=(320,320), 
                                            class_mode='binary', 
                                            batch_size=8)
```

Comment: Without code there is no way to help you. Please add it.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro apologies! I've now added the generator code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/issues/96). Apparently, the current `flow_from_dataframe` doesn't handle relative paths.

> 1. Clone my "fix_found_0_images" branch.   `git clone -b fix_found_0_images_bug
>      https://github.com/smurak/keras-preprocessing.git`
> 2. Move the "keras_preprocessing" subdirectory to your working directory.
> 3. Import it.

```
import keras
from keras_preprocessing import image
...
train_imggen = image.ImageDataGenerator(...)
```